# Почему запятая перед вставкой, а не после?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, вставная-конструкция, вводное-слово

*Разумеется, — и это очевидно — между человеком и животными есть и принципиальные различия.*

Это фраза из учебника. Запятая требуется по контексту, ее требует вводное слово. Но почему запятая перед вставкой, а не после?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Разумеется, — **и это очевидно** — между человеком и животными есть и принципиальные различия.*

В параграфе Розенталя «[Вводные и вставные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123)» видим:

> **4.** В зависимости от синтаксической структуры предложения и вставной конструкции на месте «разрыва» основного предложения, помимо **тире**, могут быть еще **запятые**. Здесь возможны следующие случаи:
> <...>
> 2) перед первым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура первой части основного предложения: *Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его, — **какой ужас!** — и руки бессильно опустились у него* — запятая закрывает придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения.

У нас структура первой части состоит из вводного слова. Его и закрываем запятой. Вставка относится ко всему высказыванию.

Comment: Почему ко всему? Только к следующему фрагменту.

Comment: @Максим Ну, тем более тогда запятая должна стоять перед первым тире. //  *Разумеется, между человеком и животными есть и принципиальные различия. И это очевидно.* У меня ко всему. :))

Comment: Вообще, я рахобрался в этом вопросе давно до вашего ответа. Но бот почему-то решил его изменить. В любом случае принимаю ваш ответ, т. к. он соответствует моим убеждениям.

Comment: @Максим  Спасибо, Максим! Я считаю, что в учебнике написано как надо.

Comment: @Максим  Жаль, что моим убеждениям противоречит, но это ничяво. (Мы что-то перестали понимать друг друга.)  А как насчет запятой, которая зрительно отделяет вставку от первой части? Тоже ничяво? А раньше говорили, что это важно.  ВСЕ говорили и меня убеждали.

Comment: @Максим Давайте уж и здесь разгромим буржуазную теорию о вставках и не будем переносить запятую. Пусть себе стоит и разделяет две вводные конструкции.  Будем последовательными в своих убеждениях. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475875/Запятая-перед-обоими-тире

Answer (score 0):

1. Можно предположить следующее.

Запятая **НЕ ПЕРЕНОСИТСЯ,** так как она не обозначает **СТРУКТУРУ** предложения, а относится к **вводному** слову:

*Разумеется, — **и это очевидно** — между человеком и животными есть и принципиальные различия.*

2. С другой стороны, вот исходное предложение: ***Разумеется**, между человеком и животными есть и принципиальные различия.*

Запятая стоит и структуру предложения вроде бы **ОБОЗНАЧАЕТ**. Тогда мы должны ее **ПЕРЕНЕСТИ**: *Разумеется — **и это очевидно**, — между человеком и животными есть и принципиальные различия.*

Этот вариант **не менее логичен,** чем первый, а в чем-то и более логичен. Отсутствие запятой показывает, **что вставка относится к первой части.** Поэтому я выберу **этот вариант** (с перенесенной запятой).

3. Можно еще записать  так (**по блокам**):

***Разумеется, и это очевидно**, — между человеком и животными есть и принципиальные различия.*

Единый знак между **вводной** частью и **основным** содержанием.

Остальное – **от лукавого**) Переносится или не переносится, обозначает структуру или не обозначает...

Comment: Можете более подробно объяснить? Я не понял, почему так и так. Желательно в ответе, а не комментариях.

Comment: Почему мы должны ее перенести? Вставка по смыслу не примыкает к вводному. Вот здесь переносится, так как вставка поясняет деепричастие: *Он встал и, прихрамывая — он был на протезе, — подошёл к окну. Когда он начинает сомневаться в себе — а это с ним изредка происходит, — он пытается стать рационалистом* — вставное предложение **примыкает** к предшествующей придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения, и запятая ставится после всей конструкции.

Comment: У Розенталя нет похожих примеров, зачем туда смотреть. Так решайте: структурная запятая или не структурная, если вся структура первой части состоит из одного вводного слова.  Так что можно выбрать любой вариант, какой нужен по ответу.  Оба варианта за уши притянуты.

Comment: Непонятно, что значит "какой нужен по ответу".  И всегда какой-нибудь вариант лучше. На примеры и их пояснения смотреть нужно. От них и пляшем. Если, например, вводное слово стоит во второй части, то и запятую ставим перед вторым тире.

Comment: Тогда лучше перенести, чтобы показать, что вставка относится к левой части.

Comment: Да почему же к левой? Она туда не относится.

Comment: Почему? Первая часть состоит из двух вводных слов.

Answer (score 0):

```
 – Тогда лучше перенести, чтобы показать, что 
   вставка относится к левой части. 

 – Да почему же к левой? Она туда не относится.
```

Вставка относится к **ПЕРВОЙ** (левой) части. Для проверки тире можно заменить **скобками.** Вместо тире можно использовать **двоеточие.** Раскрытие содержания: что именно разумеется и очевидно. ***И*** – **присоединительный** союз! Присоединяет второе вводное сочетание к первому.

Это предложение является исходным **тезисом** к дальнейшей аргументации.

***Разумеется (и это очевидно)**  – между человеком и животными есть и **принципиальные различия**. Человеческий мозг устроен сложнее, и умственные способности человека несравненно выше, чем у животных. Человек обладает высокоразвитым сознанием, членораздельной речью, ему свойственно прямохождение. Есть у человека и другие отличия, особые, присущие только ему черты строения. Обо всём этом вы узнаете в следующем разделе книги.*

Или так: ***Разумеется, и это очевидно:** между человеком и животными есть и принципиальные различия.*

Comment: Как это к первой? Перед скобками, в отличие от тире, нельзя ставить знаки — только после. А тире можно хоть куда относить.

Comment: А где вы увидели знаки?  Я содержание вашего учебника проверяю. Другая форма записи того же содержания. Мне надо доказать, что второе вводно сочетание относится к первом, дополняет его.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Это фраза из учебника. Запятая требуется по контексту, ее 
 требует вводное слово. Но почему запятая перед вставкой, а 
 не после?
```

*Разумеется, — **и это очевидно** — между человеком и животными есть и принципиальные различия.*

**РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ** (основной вариант ответа)

1. Предложение без вставки:

***Разумеется**, между человеком и животными есть и принципиальные различия.*

***"Разумеется"*** — можно также считать вводным словом или сказуемым в БСП.

Запятая относится  к **основной структуре** предложения. Вторая вставка **ПОЯСНЯЕТ** вводное слово (**разумеется, так как это очевидно**). (Вводное слово можно считать сказуемым.)

2. Это **ПОДЧИНЕННЫЙ оборот речи**, оформленный как вставка. Его можно обособить тире иди скобками, например:

*Разумеется **(и это очевидно)**, между человеком и животными есть и принципиальные различия.*

3. На основную структуру **оборот-вставка** не влияет, поэтому **нет переноса** запятой.  Запятая здесь является **СТРУКТУРНОЙ!**

**О ПРИНЯТОМ ОТВЕТЕ**

```
  У нас структура первой части состоит из вводного слова. 
  Его и  закрываем запятой. Вставка относится ко всему высказыванию.
```

1. **Неточность**: Вводное слово составляет основную структуру всего предложения, закрывать его не надо.
2. Вставка относится **к вводному слову,** так как поясняет его.

А вся конструкция (**вводное слово + вставка**) вместе входят в основную структуру предложения.

Comment: Запятая в учебнике стоит, я считаю, правильно. Если бы вставка относилась к вводному слову, их бы вместе щакрыли запятой. Но вводное слово отделили от вставки — значит, она относится к следующей части или ко всему высказыванию. Я более согласен с Александром.

Comment: У вас вся логика наоборот. Учебник правильный! Если запятую не перенесли, то вставку к вводному слову отнести нельзя. А что она туда очевидно относится по смыслу, вам неважно. И далее. Рассмотрим вариант с  БСП. Вроде бы у вас был такой вопрос, но с СПП. Там, кажется, перенесли запятую. Правда, я попросила отозвать ответ.

Comment: Sharon, извините, ничего не понятно. 1. "Вторая вставка поясняет первую". То есть "разумеется" тоже вставка? 2. "Разумеется, так как это очевидно" – это ваше понимание семантики. Мне видится другое: "и это очевидно" – чистая вставка, она относится ко всей основной структуре "Разумеется, между человеком и животными..." или даже больше к основному высказыванию. 3.  "Запятая здесь является структурной!" Да, всё верно, я так и написал в ответе. Единственное, что, может быть, не совсем точно написал, так это "закрыть" (по аналогии с придаточным, как в правиле). Ну не "закрыть", так "отделить".

Comment: Неточность я исправила.  // Семантику можно понимать по-разному. В первой части находятся две вводные конструкции, которые вместе относятся ко всему предложению. Зачем же их делить, это нелогично.  // А структурный характер запятой – это основной вопрос. То ли она вводное слово  у вас закрывает, то ли структуру обозначает.

Comment: Разве это не одно и то же? Закрывая (отделяя) вводное, она обозначает структуру.

Comment: В данном случае две функции совпали, впрочем, как и наши решения. Вопрос о корректном объяснении. Нужно было сказать, что это структурная запятая, Не всякая закрывающая запятая является структурной, например https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476721/Оформление-вставной-конструкции-у-Чехова   Есть оформление этого предложения с перенесенной запятой.  Вот еще пример на тему  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475875/Запятая-перед-обоими-тире  Никто не пришел ответить.  Известного ответа нет! На учебник нельзя сослаться.

Comment: Мне кажется, любая запятая является структурной. И с сёстрами тоже: она закрывает обособленное приложение, как вы пишете "субструктуру".

Comment: Не все так думают. Почему У Чехова другой вариант?  Вот и Максим стал другие предлагать. Определить обособленность не всегда просто, разный бывает синтаксис. Впрочем, это мое мнение, просто хотелось обсудить на форуме. Но не получилось, как видите. Всего три участника,  и один из них судия.  Впрочем, еще был учебник...