# Какие запятые нужно поставить при оформлении вставки?

Tags: вставная-конструкция

Рассмотрим предложение:

*Разумеется(?) — **об этом уже говорилось раньше**(?)— между человеком и животными есть и принципиальные различия.*

Здесь использована **другая вставка** по сравнению с предложением   **[из этой темы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475854/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5).**

Изменится ли решение относительно **постановки запятых**?

Answer (score 0):

А как должно поменяться?

Если бы вставка относилась к вводному слову, то нельзя было бы убрать только его — потому что будет некорректный смысл. Но здесь смысл не поменяется — значит, вставка относится к следующей части высказывания, поэтому вводное слово отделяем в начале, а не в конце:

*Разумеется, — об этом уже говорилось раньше — между человеком и животными есть и принципиальные различия*.

Comment: Я бы так написала: Разумеется — об этом уже говорилось раньше, — между человеком и животными есть и принципиальные различия. Перенесенная  запятая, так как обозначает основную структуру предложения.  А у вас некрасиво выглядит. Я ведь могу здесь увидеть БСП, где разумеется —  сказуемое.