# Трудный случай при оформлении вставной конструкции

Tags: вставная-конструкция

В ПАС под ред. Лопатина **[§97](https://%C2%A798)** есть такое предложение:

*Называли фамилии мужей и братьев, **– живы ли, здоровы ли они? –** как будто этот военный мог знать по именам все тысячи рабочих, дравшихся на всех фронтах (А. Т.).*

Как **объяснить** выбор знаков?

Comment: Вопрос хороший, плюс от меня.

Comment: Спасибо,  еще ответ почитайте.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, я ошибаюсь, но мне кажется, что  в этом предложении нет вставной конструкции, а имеется сложное предложение с союзной и бессоюзной связью, поэтому  после первого предложения надо поставить двоеточие, чтобы показать, что дальше разъясняется, какие вопросы задавали жены, спрашивая военного. Таким образом, предложение может выглядеть так:  Называли фамилии мужей и братьев: живы ли, здоровы ли они? – как будто этот военный мог знать по именам все тысячи рабочих, дравшихся на всех фронтах (А. Т.).

Comment: Ничего себе! Участники, когда-либо бывшие здесь — давние, — возвращаются потихоньку.

Comment: Спасибо, Виктор, за ответ, он мне понравился (голос от меня),  так как написан по слуху (так, как мы слышим его). Двоеточие соответствует единому знаку (увеличенная пауза), при замене получим: Называли фамилии мужей и братьев: живы ли, здоровы ли они? – как будто этот военный мог знать по именам...  То есть это вариант из литературного текста.  Но к вашему оформлению будет вопрос: вопросительный знак в середине предложения используется только во вставных конструкциях.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Почему тогда здесь запятая не поглотилась, а перенеслась 
   со второго тире на первое: Называли фамилии мужей и 
   братьев, — живы ли, здоровы ли они? — как будто этот 
   военный мог знать по именам все тысячи рабочих, дравшихся 
   на всех фронтах? Вопросительный знак должен был «съесть» 
   запятую, но почему не «съел», а «сдвинул» к первому тире, 
   где она стоять не должна?
```

*Называли фамилии мужей и братьев, **– живы ли, здоровы ли они?** – как будто этот военный мог знать по именам все тысячи рабочих, дравшихся на всех фронтах (А. Т.).*

**Пояснение**

1. Заменим вопросительный знак **запятой и уберем тире**:

*Называли фамилии мужей и братьев,  // **живы ли, здоровы ли они,**  // как будто этот военный мог знать по именам все тысячи рабочих,  дравшихся на всех фронтах?*

2. Это **сложное предложение,** три предикативные основы,  обе запятые **структурные.**
3. Если второе предложение оформить как вставку, то обе **структурные** запятые нужно поставить.

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**

**Если решать по блокам,** то ответ получается **другой**:

*Называли фамилии мужей и братьев **– / живы ли, здоровы ли они, – //**  будто этот военный мог знать по именам все тысячи рабочих,  дравшихся на всех фронтах?*

**Первый блок:** *Называли фамилии мужей и братьев –  живы ли, здоровы ли они.* БСП, отношения изъяснительные.

**Второй блок:**  *Будто этот военный мог знать по именам все тысячи рабочих,  дравшихся на всех фронтах.*

Отношения между блоками **присоединительные** со значением сравнения, ставится **единый знак.**

**По смыслу похоже,** так как вставка относится к **первой** части.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

В этом предложении важно разобраться в том, какая связь (по Лопатину) является **основной**. Другими словами, где проходит **граница** между двумя частями предложения? Если поставить двоеточие, то этот знак будет основным:

*Называли фамилии мужей и братьев:  // **живы ли, здоровы ли они?** - как будто этот военный мог знать по именам все тысячи рабочих,  дравшихся на всех фронтах?*

Но мне думается, что основной знак-пауза — это **присоединительное** тире, там предложение делится **на две части.**

Comment: Потом отвечу на это, сейчас нет особого желания.

Comment: Хорошо, а может, еще кто ответит.  Интересно послушать.

Comment: Я согласен с вариантом, где запятая только перед вторым тире. А эти структурные запятые перед обоими тире... Не думаю, что так. Вставки не являются членами предложения, поэтому их не так запятыми выделяют, а по структуре частей слева и справа. Поэтому я верным считаю только второй вариант.

Comment: Хотя, может, использовали симметрию, но один знак поглотился. Хотя я прка не знаю, зачем ее используют. Задал вопрос на тему симметрии.

Comment: А можно ближе к Розенталю?  Структурные и перенесенные запятые и все такое. Мы же по ним отчитываемся.  Члены предложения? А вот  в недавнем вопросе  слово "разумеется" можно считать сказуемым или вводным словом, и это не мешало вам найти единственно верное решение 
 https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475854/Почему-запятая-перед-вставкой-а-не-после